# C and file permissions

Tags: c, linux, file-permissions

I am using Ubuntu Lucid Lynx

is it possible to write data in a file through a C program which has read only permission. If it's not possible, then is there any way to give sudo access to the C program.

For files without permissions, I would save the data in a string. Then i would open the file with write option:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(file_path,"w")
fputs(string,fp);
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Personally, I think this isn't about programming but Unix OS usage. Voting to move to SU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unix generally what you'd want to do is make the program's executable owned by root, world executable, then set the SUID bit on it.

```
chown root filename
chmod 4775 filename
```

See [chomd docs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) for exactly what the bits mean, but all together this means that whenever someone runs this executable, they get the executable process' user ID set to the owner's (root).

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot write to a read-only file, that would undermine the whole point of read-only.  As for giving root access to a c program, you could always run it as root or as someone who has permissions to modify the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are the owner of the file you can change the permissions with [chmod](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/chmod/). If you are not the owner you can use [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bit to acces the file, but this really should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have the program elevate itself to sudo status while its running.
And that is a bloody good thing. 
If that was possible every virus would have the ability to take over any system.

The program needs to be started with the proper access-rights from the start.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but not in a standard cross-platform way.

On Unix systems, use `chmod`. It should be in `<sys/stat.h>`

See [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Function_details).

If you need root privilage, try:

```
if(fp == NULL)
    execvp("sudo", argv);
```

Comment: What if the program has no permissions to chmod it?